# how to hide next & prev from owl carousel component?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have 5 carousel component in a page.. each component contains 2/5 items and showing 3 in a slide...
It is to hide the prev , next button from the component having less than 3 items..

please suggest the code.

Comment: Please add your code and have a look at the documentation: http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing ... Section 3. defaults. You can use `navigation : false`. You can set it, if your component has less than 3 items.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(".owl-carousel .items").length() < 3) {
    //hide buttons
    $(".owl-carousel .btn.next").hide();
    $(".owl-carousel .btn.prev").hide();
}
```

You should adjust to a bit your code

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css. if you are using version 2

```
.owl-nav .owl-prev.disabled, .owl-nav .owl-next.disabled {
    display: none !important
}
```

**NB** It also depend on how many items you want to show in slide view.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            nav:false,
        })
    </script>
```